# GeneXus - Exposing BC Transaction as REST Web Service - Return all rules validations at once

Tags: rest, genexus

I do have a BC Transaction exposed as a REST Web Service.
It does have multiple validation rules verifying empty Attributes.
But when we call it as a Web Service (Postman), it only returns one validation message at a time.

Is there any way to return all the validation messages at once, just like it does when called programatically from a Procedure or a Web Panel?

I've tested it an searched for a configuration to solve this in GX16, GX17 and even GX18, but found nothing even in the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

At the version level, check the properties that are under Client Side Validation Behavior [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work for this specific functionality. I've already marked it as "All at once", but it keep on returning only one error message at once.